# Windows 10: Unable to open processes as Administrator

Tags: windows, windows-10, virus, administrator

I'm having a problem I found today: I'm being unable to open any app in Administrator mode in my Windows 10, most notably Task Manager won't open. (any app in normal mode can be open such as Firefox which I'm using to write this) In fact, I first thought it was only a problem with TM which won't open even by directly clicking on its .exec file under System32 folder, but then I noticed how previously a game that only starts with Administrator privileges didn't open. So I studied further and discovered that Process Monitor, which opens normally in normal mode, also wouldn't open as Administrator. What happens in such cases is that after a long period of waiting I get an error message simply stating "The service didn't responded to the start or control requisition in suficcient time" (rought translation from Portuguese).

I'm suspicious this might be result of virus infection, so I'm going to do a full clean up tomorrow. I searched something on the web and found comments about fixing .NET Framework, but that was for Windows 8. If this is probably the result of something else, not a virus, or there is a known fix for this, I'ld like to know.

Comment: And you are sure that you have admin rights? Maybe you are just really not authorized?

Comment: \o/ This is my private PC at home and everything worked fine for the last 5 years regarding having Admin rights (or the last months considering the update to Windows 10). I haven't changed any configuration regarding that nor has anybody changed it for sure.

Comment: @Aganju btw just to verify I checked and my account is still marked as Administrator of the system (maybe a bug could have change the registry or something and changed the user previleges, but it would seem that wasn't the case)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved although I'm not exactly sure what solved. I did a full scan in my PC and found 4 viruses. After all being removed, I restarted my machine and found out and suffered from power loss. After restarting my PC when power got back, I restarted my machine asking for Windows/boot to do a start scan; nothing was found. Once my PC was in W10 again, I discovered there was a big Windows 10 update to make. So I downloaded and installed it and after restarting my PC one last time, I discovered things were back to normal.

So I suppose something in the middle of the previously mentioned steps solved my problem.